# representing $n-1$ as a sum of factors of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Motivation: In group theory it is proved that the center of a p-group is non-trivial. Essentially the proof is making use of the fact that for any number of the form $n=p^k$ where $p$ is prime, there is no way to represent $n-1$ as a sum of prime factors of $n$ (because all factors divide $p$ while $n-1$ does not)

Question: Are there any other numbers $n$ such that $n-1$ cannot be written as a sum of non-trivial factors of $n$, allowing for repetitions?

I suspect that the answer is no because there seems to be too many ways of playing with the factors in the sum once there are two of them. I was also able to prove there is no such $n$ in a few simple cases but I think there might be a proof for the general case as well.

Comment: As a trivial way: $1$ is a factor of $n$ and $n-1$ can be written as a sum of $1$'s. In your question do you want it to include that the factors be prime?

Comment: @Dave Presumably only proper factors are intended -- that would eliminate the trivial solution you mention.

Comment: When you say "as a sum of factors", do you mean to allow repetitions?  If you *don't* allow repetitions, then any deficient number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deficient_number) would be an example of this.

Comment: On the other hand if you *do* allow repetitions, then any even $n$ (that is not a power of $2$) has the property that $n-1$ can be written as a sum of factors of $n$.

Comment: Edited question for clarification. I meant to only include proper factors and allow for repetitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Claim:**

If $n$ is a positive integer with at least two distinct prime factors, then $n-1$ can be expressed as a sum of nontrivial (i.e., factors not equal to $1$) positive integer factors of $n$ (possibly repeated).

**Proof:**

Since $n$ has at least two distinct prime factors, we can write $n=ab$, where $a,b$ are integers with $a,b > 1$, and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

It follows by a well known elementary result (and easily proved), that every integer $m$ greater than $ab-a-b$ can be expressed as $m=ax+by$, for some nonnegative integers $x,y$.

Now simply note that $n=ab$ implies $n-1 > ab-a-b$.

Comment: Together with the OP's argument above we have that $n−1$ can be written as the sum of the factors of $n$ iff and $n$ has two distinct prime factors

Comment: Yes, agreed. By the way, in this context, the OP means the question asker.

Comment: Isn't that how I use the expression? "Together with the questions asker's argument above we have a nice little general statement: Then I give this statement."

I think this sentence "$n-1$ can be written as the sum of the factors of $n$ iff $n$ has two distinct prime factors" may be a nice little thing to append to the bottom of your answer because it's a succinct way of summarizing this page's conclusion. I am cognizant that it's not really of great benefit to the OP who already understands his own argument.